# Foscam IP camera: get snapshot

Tags: c#, image, video, ip-camera

I'm trying to get a snapshot from my Foscam FI9816P camera.
I'm using the following address:

```
http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=[USER]&pwd=[PWD]
```

and this works fine from the browser, showing the image snapshot.

Programmatically, I've been using in the past another camera, providing the ("raw") JPG image as the response:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] JpgFile = null;
    JpgFile = client.DownloadData(sWebCam);
    // ...
}
```

Now, this new camera is providing a "HTML page" as the response, containing the image link as an embedded `img` tag:

```
<html><body><img src="../snapPic/Snap_20150729-164352.jpg"/></body></html>
```

Now, the point is that if I point to the image address:

```
http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/snapPic/Snap_20150729-164352.jpg
```

I get a **404 - Not found** error.
I can't see what is going on "behind the scenes" to get the image; above all, I don't know how to get the "raw" image JPG in C#.

**Edit [1]:**

I got this working, parsing the image tag inside the html, and sending a second "GET" request:

```
sWebCam = String.Concat("http://", cConfig.WebcamIpAddress, "/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=[USER]&pwd=[PWD]");
try
{
    JpgFile = client.DownloadData(sWebCam);

    string sTmp = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(JpgFile);
    sTmp = sTmp.Substring(sTmp.IndexOf("<img src=\"") + "<img src=\"".Length);
    sTmp = sTmp.Substring(0, sTmp.IndexOf("\"/>"));
    sTmp = sTmp.Replace("..", "");

    sWebCam = string.Concat("http://", cConfig.WebcamIpAddress, sTmp);
    JpgFile = client.DownloadData(sWebCam);
}
```

So, i'm wondering why accessing the final image address *from the browser* (`http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/snapPic/Snap_20150729-164352.jpg`) is giving out a 404. This is the original reason why I was confused...

Comment: So you download the html, parse out the img url and download that? Have you tried inserting a delay between the two?

Comment: The `../` is very important at the beginning, its actually changing directories.

Comment: Just edited my question: it's working now... just got some confusion on HTTP GET requests....

Comment: I suppose camera checks `Referer` field in your request. The refefer should point to previous request to `CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2`

Comment: @RomanR. I supposed the same, but I tried to replay the same request inside Fiddler, which _seems_ to reuse the same `Referer`, but I still get a 404.

Comment: It might be cookie or additional HTTP header. There should be something that connects the two requests. Most IP cams don't do this of course, but once in a while there are crazy anti-human implementations like the one you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, as snapPicture2 function was supposed to return the "raw" image (differently from snapPicture, returning instead it wrapped in an HTML page), but changed its behaviour in FI9816P firmware 1.9.2.12 due to an alleged bug (reference: http://foscam.us/forum/fi9816p-broken-snappicture2-bug-t13482.html).

In my existing system I required the raw image, this led me to further investigation having as output a NodeJS module (which btw is available on GitHub: https://github.com/andreatondo/foscam-snapshot-nodejs) to workaround the problem.

To answer your question, it appears that Foscam saves the image in */snapPic/* path just for the time required to serve your request, and then deletes it. This is why it returns a 404 when you try to use the link in HTML page.

This just to confirm that your approach is the right one, at least until Foscam fixes the issue on a next firmware update.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget` for download :

```
wget -m -p -k "http://192.168.8.108:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=XXX&pwd=XXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t use it any further, but I wanted to share.

```
wget -m -p "https://x.x.x.x:443/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=xxxx&pwd=xxxx" -O "image.jpg" --no-check-certificate
```

This downloads a `.jpg` in the root folder of the user—where the scripts runs from?!?

I tested this on Foscam C2M.

Comment: What do you mean that you couldn’t use this any further? Could you [edit[ your answer to clarify that.